# Show inputs by number choose

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input

I wanted to build something and I just can't do that :O
What i'v tried to do is something like..
 If I write 2 in and input it will show me 2 inputs, if I write 3 it will show 3   inputs fields .. 
I'v tried to work on this with js but I don't success..
But I need that can't choose more than 10.
Thanks for help, sorry for my bad English.

Edit:
I write this code:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">

    var DivTxt = new Array()
    DivTxt[0] = "Please Select Priority"
    DivTxt[1] = "Priority Low: The selection is Low"
    DivTxt[2] = "Priority Normal: The selection is Normal"
    DivTxt[3] = "Priority High: The selection is High"
    DivTxt[3] = "Priority Critical: The selection is Critical"

    function getText(slction){
    txtSelected = slction.selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById('textDiv').innerHTML = DivTxt[txtSelected];
    }
    </script>


<Select class="body_text" name="critical" onchange="getText(this)">
<option value="Select"> Select </option>
   <option value="LOW"> Low </option>
   <option value="NORMAL"> Normal </option>
   <option value="HIGH"> High </option>
   <option value="CRITICAL"> Critical </option>      
</select>
<div id="textDiv" style="color:Green; font-family:Calibri; font-size:small; font-weight:bold"> </div>
```

But this code just write the selected text in the div.
I want to if you select number (example 3) it will show 3 Div's

Comment: Where is the JS code you've written?

Comment: I don't know so match to work with JS and i delete the code..
I need help with this..

Comment: I have tried to use codes from some tutorials but I can't find tutorial for what I want..

Comment: please add code for what you have tried till now

Comment: @KillsProfessor On selection of ,say, `High`, how many div's you want to be added?...Your title and explanation are two different things, creating confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your expecting ? see this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/selvadevel/pwnarqsb/

```
<input type="text" id="check" value="">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#check").blur(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val()+" input");
}); 
});
```

Comment: see this fiddle i think this is your expectation  http://jsfiddle.net/selvadevel/pwnarqsb/2/

Comment: That's really close..
I want that if you write number 2 so 2 inputs will appear after
If you don't understand yet I mean that I write 10 inputs code with html and gives them "display:none" and when I write number 2 it will do 2 inputs to display: block..

Comment: Where i write here select box only available ?